# Constants of motion for non-chaotric billiards

Tags: billiards, integrable-systems

As I understand it, for a mechanical system, each symmetry leads to a constant of motion. For integrable systems, the number of constants of motion equals the number of degrees of freedom.

So take 2D square and circular billiards tables. What are their constants of motion? For the circular table, it looks like angular momentum is a constant of motion. For the square table, it looks like $\left|v_x\right|$ and $\left|v_y\right|$ (the magnitudes of the x and y components of the velocities) are constant.

Are those indeed constants of motion? If so, are there more (or other ways to view the constants of motion)? (It seems like there should be a second for the circular table.)

Comment: Energy is conserved in both cases; this can be interpreted as arising from time-invariance.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think that's also true for non-integrable billiard systems. Shouldn't there be another constant of motion for the circular table?

Comment: Ok, I might understand: constant $\left|v_x\right|$ and $\left|v_y\right|$ together imply energy conservation, so there are only two independent constants of motion in that case. And, like you said, energy conservation is the other constant of motion for the circular table.

Comment: What about the ellipse?

Comment: The Laplace–Runge–Lenz vector? I think I've seen the answer somewhere, but it wasn't straightforward.

Comment: I should add that, I still have some questions about the constants of motion. I've read that constants of motion come from symmetries, and it looks like those tables have a ton of symmetries.E.g. the square has 4x rotational symmetry, mirror symmetry across 4 axes, and time reversal symmetry. So, are there more constants of motion, or do not all symmetries lead to constants of motion?